# Python Server Pages Implementations

Tags: php, python, apache, mod-python

I've been a PHP developer for quite awhile, and I've heard good things about using Python for web scripting. After a bit of research, I found mod_python, which integrates with Apache to allow Python Server Pages, which seem very similar to the PHP pages I'm used to. I also found a mod_wsgi which looks similar.

I was wondering which implementation the good people of Stack Overflow would recommend for someone who wants good integration with Apache and MySQL and similar functionality to PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe **mod_wsgi** is the preferred option to mod_python:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/

Some performance benchmarks seem to suggest that mod_wsgi performs much better also.

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/PerformanceEstimates

Comment: Can mod_wsgi handle Python Server Pages in the same way that this does? http://webpython.codepoint.net/mod_python_psp_hello_world More specifically, does it allow me to embed blocks of Python into an HTML page using delimiters?

Comment: I think Python Server Pages is a feature of mod_python - so prob not, somebody correct me if I'm wrong here.  However, there are loads of templating languages with Python (http://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating)... and (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98245/what-is-your-single-favorite-python-templating-engine).

Why do you want to use PSP in particular?

Comment: I like the way PHP is embedded into HTML, and I wanted to do the same with Python.

Comment: Ok, you should take a look at Spyce if you're going to go down the mod_wsgi route - http://spyce.sourceforge.net/docs/doc-intro_rationale.html It's very similar with the same design principles as PSP.

Comment: The long term viability of mod_python is currently also in question. This and use of PSP was just today begin discussed on mod_python list. See 'http://www.modpython.org/pipermail/mod_python/2009-July/026276.html'. Use of an alternate templating system on top of WSGI is definitely a better long term solution.